# simple angularjs snippet not working in jssfiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I am trying to run a simple angularjs code in jsfiddle but it doesn't work when I give a name to my module or define a controller.

eg  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshay/veqo1cpq/1/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/><br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/><br/>
    <br/>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>
```

bu when I remove the controller attribute and the name of the app it works fine.
eg.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshay/veqo1cpq/)

```
<div ng-app="">

    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/><br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/><br/>
    <br/>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>
```

Why is it so??

PS:  including angularjs v1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is wrapped in an `onload` handler by default in jsfiddle.

Therefore the code isn't available in global namespace

Works fine changing to `no wrap in head`

http://jsfiddle.net/veqo1cpq/3/

Comment: it solves the problem but does not answer the question. Why is it when i fork the controller and module it stops working and works without it

Comment: because angular is using rootScope and it doesn't need to find any functions or modules because none are declared. If you don't define a controller, scope will be `$rootScope`

Answer (score 2):

It is one of the settings of jsfiddle.

You need to select option `no wrap - in <head>` and all will be working fine

Here is your fixed link http://jsfiddle.net/veqo1cpq/2/

Comment: it solves the problem but does not answer the question. Why is it when i fork the controller and module it stops working and works without it